# JHipster : Generate MongoDB entities with JHipster Domain Language (JDL)

Tags: java, mongodb, jhipster, jdl

I'm trying JHipster with a MongoDB database. For my example I would like to store Books. To do that I would like to use the JDL format to be able to generate entities, repositories, services, dtos…

This is my actual JDL file:
And it works :

```
entity Book {
    name String required
    date LocalDate required
}

dto all with mapstruct
paginate all with pager
service all with serviceImpl
```

Now, I would like to add the notion that a `Book` can be written by an `Author`.

I can add an entity `Author`:

```
entity Author {
        firstane String required
        lastname LocalDate required
    }
```

My specific question is: How can I associate an `Author` and a `Book`?

The documentation has this example :

```
relationship OneToMany {
  Author{book} to Book{writer(name) required}
}
```

But that's not working because NoSQL databases don't support relationships. So, how can I achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can generate collection in the database of Mongodb when importing from jdl ?

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said exactly what you want to do with your entities. With NoSQL databases this becomes a more important question. Let's assume you want to return an author and all their books as a single document.

Here are some options:

- Have two separate entities with no formal relationship in JHipster. Create a [service](https://jhipster.github.io/creating-a-service/) that looks up an author using the Author Repository and also fetches the books with the same author id using the Book Repository.
- Have a single Author entity in JHipster. Model books as an [array of embdedded documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#arrays) for each `Author`. Unfortunately JHipster does not seem to allow you to define list types as entity [fields](https://jhipster.github.io/jdl/#annexes) so you will have to add this to the Java code yourself.
- You may be able to use the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#pipe._S_lookup) feature in mongodb 3.2 to fetch Books for a given Author. The [`DBRef`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references) feature in spring-data-mongo might help in this case.